# child table foreign keys auto populated with same values from primary key of parent table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I created two tables with one primary and foreign keys in tables. I want to write the code that when i insert into table1 and then go to insert into table2, so the value in table2 foreign key column that reference to primary key of table1 will be auto inserted same as primary key of table 1.

I am creating these tables and database for my android application in android studio and using sqlite3.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR, 
    fathername VARCHAR,
    dob DATE, 
    age INT 
);

CREATE TABLE table2(
    m_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    treatdate DATE, 
    hospital VARCHAR,
    city VARCHAR, 
    id2 INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES table1(id) 
);
```

Comment: Foreign keys can only help with inserts in that they constrain what can be added to the column.  So when you populate Table2 you need to have a value in ID2 that exists in Table1. There is no way that Table2 can magically know which value in Table1 you want to reference.

Comment: Insert a row into the first table, get its rowid (with however your bindings provide the `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` function), and use that number when inserting a row into the second table.

Comment: Kindly give me some code for explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SQLiteDatabse **insert** method, it returns the **rowid** on the insert row (for tables that are not defined with WITHOUT ROWID). As you have used INTEGER PRIMARY KEY for the definition of the **id** column it is an alias of the **rowid** column, so the value assigned to **id** will be returned (if the column was successfully inserted else -1 is returned).

e.g.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("name","Fred");
cv.put("fathername","George");
cv.put("dob","2000-01-01");
cv.put("age",21)
long returned_id = your_sqlite_database.insert("table1",null,cv);
```

**returned_id** will be the id of the row inserted into **table1**.

Typically the above would be within a method that takes the name, fathername, dob and age as parameters and that returns the id.

## Working Example

### The Database Helper (subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper) DBHelper.java

This creates the database and tables and defines 3 methods :-

- **addTable1Row** to add a row to table1 that returns a long with the id of the inserted row.
- **addTable2Row** to add a row to table2 that returns a long with the id of the inserted row
- **getAllFromTable1JoinedWithTable2** does as the method name implies
- **Note** the onConfigure method of SQLiteOpenHelper is overridden to turn Foreign Key support on (by default it is not on)

:-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_TABLE1 = "table1";
    public static final String TBL_TABLE2 = "table2";

    public static final String COL_TABLE1_ID = "id";
    public static final String COL_TABLE1_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_TABLE1_FATHERNAME = "fathername";
    public static final String COL_TABLE1_DOB = "dob";
    public static final String COL_TABLE1_AGE = "age";

    public static final String COL_TABLE2_ID = "m_id";
    public static final String COL_TABLE2_TREATDATE = "treatdate";
    public static final String COL_TABLE2_HOSPITAL = "hospital";
    public static final String COL_TABLE2_CITY = "city";
    public static final String COL_TABLE2_ID2 = "id2";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String table1_crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_TABLE1 + "(" +
                COL_TABLE1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_TABLE1_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COL_TABLE1_FATHERNAME + " TEXT, " +
                COL_TABLE1_DOB + " TEXT, " +
                COL_TABLE1_AGE + " INTEGER" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(table1_crtsql);

        String table2_crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_TABLE2 + "(" +
                COL_TABLE2_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_TABLE2_TREATDATE + " TEXT, " +
                COL_TABLE2_HOSPITAL + " TEXT, " +
                COL_TABLE2_CITY + " TEXT, " +
                COL_TABLE2_ID2 + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TBL_TABLE1 + "(" + COL_TABLE1_ID + ")" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(table2_crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }

    public long addTable1Row(String name, String fathername, String dob, int age) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TABLE1_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_TABLE1_FATHERNAME,fathername);
        cv.put(COL_TABLE1_DOB,dob);
        cv.put(COL_TABLE1_AGE,age);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_TABLE1,null,cv);
    }

    public long addTable2Row(String treatdate, String hospital, String city, long table1_reference) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TABLE2_TREATDATE,treatdate);
        cv.put(COL_TABLE2_HOSPITAL,hospital);
        cv.put(COL_TABLE2_CITY,city);
        cv.put(COL_TABLE2_ID2,table1_reference);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_TABLE2,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllFromTable1JoinedWithTable2() {
        String tables = TBL_TABLE1 +
                " JOIN " + TBL_TABLE2 +
                " ON " +
                TBL_TABLE2 + "." + COL_TABLE2_ID2 +
                " = " +
                TBL_TABLE1 + "." + COL_TABLE1_ID;
        return mDB.query(tables,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- Note AUTOINCREMENT hasn't been used as it is unecessary, defined column types, rather than derived column types have been used (not that it has any impact)

### MainActivity.java

This instantiates a DBHelper objects and then uses the available methods to add some rows to each of the tables. 2 rows are added to table1 and 3 are added to table2 (Fred has 2 hospital visits).

The data is then extracted according to the relationship between table2 and table1 so 3 rows are extracted. These are dumped to the system log.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBhlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBhlpr = new DBHelper(this);

        //Add Fred
        long parentid = mDBhlpr.addTable1Row("Fred","George","2000-01-01",19);
        // Add a hospital visit for Fred
        mDBhlpr.addTable2Row("2019-01-01","Prince Fred","Timbukto",parentid);

        //Add Mary and a hospital visit all in one go
        mDBhlpr.addTable2Row("2019-01-02","St Barts","Springfield",
                mDBhlpr.addTable1Row("Mary","Tom","1999-12-23",19)
        );

        // Another hospital visit for Fred
        mDBhlpr.addTable2Row("2019-01-03","John Radcliffe","Oxford",parentid);

        // Get the joined data and dump it to the log
        Cursor csr = mDBhlpr.getAllFromTable1JoinedWithTable2();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    }
}
```

## Result

The log includes :-

```
 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@3fd1bbe9
 I/System.out: 0 {
 I/System.out:    id=1
 I/System.out:    name=Fred
 I/System.out:    fathername=George
 I/System.out:    dob=2000-01-01
 I/System.out:    age=19
 I/System.out:    m_id=1
 I/System.out:    treatdate=2019-01-01
 I/System.out:    hospital=Prince Fred
 I/System.out:    city=Timbukto
 I/System.out:    id2=1
 I/System.out: }
 I/System.out: 1 {
 I/System.out:    id=2
 I/System.out:    name=Mary
 I/System.out:    fathername=Tom
 I/System.out:    dob=1999-12-23
 I/System.out:    age=19
 I/System.out:    m_id=2
 I/System.out:    treatdate=2019-01-02
 I/System.out:    hospital=St Barts
 I/System.out:    city=Springfield
 I/System.out:    id2=2
 I/System.out: }
 I/System.out: 2 {
 I/System.out:    id=1
 I/System.out:    name=Fred
 I/System.out:    fathername=George
 I/System.out:    dob=2000-01-01
 I/System.out:    age=19
 I/System.out:    m_id=3
 I/System.out:    treatdate=2019-01-03
 I/System.out:    hospital=John Radcliffe
 I/System.out:    city=Oxford
 I/System.out:    id2=1
 I/System.out: }
 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

Comment: Thanks. But if we define this long parentid in one activity and used it in another activity, so what would we do?

Comment: @BrittOval you pass the id (parentid) via an intent extra to the activity and retrieve the value from the intent in the other activity. As per [Start another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Comment: i need some more help About intent to pass the parentid from activity to another.

Comment: Source Activity :
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i= new Intent(crt_profile.this,medical_record.class);

                long parentid =  dbHelper.addTable1Row(Name.getText().toString(),
                       Fathername.getText().toString(), DOB.getText().toString());                           i.putExtra( FOREIGN_ID ,parentid);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

Comment: Destination activity                                                                                                     Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String id2 = intent.getStringExtra(crt_profile.FOREIGN_ID);

Comment: @BrittOval As parentid is long use intent.[getLongExtra(FOREIGN_ID,-1)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getLongExtra(java.lang.String,%20long)). -1 being the default value returned if the Extra couldn't be retrieved (my guess is that yours returned "" (empty string) as the String Extra FOREIGN_ID doesn't exist).

Comment: OK. now what would be write here in 4th column of my table 2 ?                                              add_medical.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                litedatabase = m_helper.getWritableDatabase();
                m_helper.addTable2Row(tdate.getText().toString(),
                        medicine.getText().toString(),
                        diagnosis.getText().toString(),  ?  );

Comment: That should be the parentid that you've extracted from the Intent Extra.

Comment: i want to show my data like this, name from table1 on top and then all data from table 2 . How could i do this? help

Comment: How  could I pass my parentid value to listview ?

Comment: Kindly help @MikeT